# No ARIMA model fits my data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I tried to fit an ARIMA model to a data, but no success!! I shared my data and the R-codes below to check any mistake!
dt=c(15,18,13,16,11,14,19,20,16,17,13,11,13,15,8,12,15,14,15,15,18,11,13,15,11,11, 8,10,16,14,17,8,14,11,10,13,13,10,11,14,12,17,20,18,14,14,19,11,14,17,13,14,13,
15,16,10,15,20,16,7,15,12)

```
ft = auto.arima(dt)
pd = forecast(ft,h=5)
plot(pd)
```

The plot of forecast via `plot(pd)` is shown below:

[image: Forecast]
Let's look at the forecast points: the next 5 point forecasts are fixed at "**13.87097**"!!
So, I am not sure that this is the right solution for my problem!
[image: Forecast points]

How can I fix this problem and find an appropriate ARIMA model?

***UPDATED** after discussion:*
First of all, I am surprised that this topic has been closed without solving the problem!

Second, I aim to forecast the next $Y_t$'s for these data, but it's not satisfactory.

Third the theory behind of such ARIMA modeling and forecast are on my interest too.

Fourth, still I couldn't get my answer, hence, I request the dear ADMIN(s) of this forum to re-OPEN this topic, so that others can participate. Solved the problem, the topic can be closed and archived for future reference.

Comment: Why do you think ARIMA(0,0,0) is not the best model  for your data among the class of ARIMA(p,d,q) models?

Comment: Dear @RichardHardy, Aim of fitting an ARIMA model to data is to forecast/predict for future, I think. So, by ARIMA(0,0,0) you cannot do it, because you have only "intercept/constant value!"

Comment: Of course you can do it, even if the forecast looks very simple. Suppose you have an i.i.d. sample, guess what forecast will be the most accurate? One from ARIMA(0,0,0) model. Processes like stock returns are best forecast with ARIMA(0,0,0), while other ARIMA and non-ARIMA forecasts lead to larger forecast errors.

Comment: The question was closed without solving your problem because it is unclear why you think some model other than $0,0,0$ should fit your data. The $0,0,0$ model is perfectly valid for predicting: in the absence of any pattern, the best prediction is always guessing the observed average. Why must there be some kind of ARIMA pattern?

Comment: Dear @Dave appreciated fro your for explanation. With ARIMA(0,0,0), $\hat{Y_T}= Constant + e_t$, which means that all future values are fixed value, which is in contrast with the previous values and trends! Based on the 62 observation, we see some fluctuation, but for the next 10 forecast it's a fixed value of "13.87097," in my case. That's why I am afraid that the model is not OK!! Need more explanation, do't hesitate to discuss, please.

Comment: ARIMA$(0,0,0)$ doesn’t suggest that all of your future values will be the same. The model means that your best net for guessing future values is to keep guessing $13.87097$. The $\epsilon$ error term says that you will have some variability. Think about it this way: if you want to guess the values I draw from $N(0,1)$, do you guess random values or do you guess $0$ itself? The latter type of guessing doesn’t mean that you really think I’ll keep drawing $0$, however. (I want you to think about that question and post an answer with an explanation.)

Answer (score 1):

Because it is the best ARIMA fit for your data, there is likely no mistake.

The 63rd observation is indeed a big outlier. It is ~30 times bigger than standard deviation for other observations. Even if there was some autocorrelation structure in your data, you would often not be able to discern it with such outlier, so trying to remove it is a good approach.

If you remove the outlier, ARIMA(0, 0, 0) is still the best ARIMA model for your data. There is no discernible autocorrelation structure, it looks like white noise.

You can see it by yourself by looking at the autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation functions. All autocorrelations are statistically indistinguishable from 0:

```
dt = dt[-63] # Remove outlier

acf(dt)
pacf(dt)
```

[image: acf]
[image: pacf]

You can also try fitting specific AR and MA models manually to get a better feel why auto.arima selected ARIMA(0, 0, 0):

```
> arima(dt, c(1, 0, 0))

Call:
arima(x = dt, order = c(1, 0, 0))

Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept
      0.1652    13.8686
s.e.  0.1246     0.4585

sigma^2 estimated as 9.14:  log likelihood = -156.58,  aic = 319.16
> arima(dt, c(0, 0, 1))

Call:
arima(x = dt, order = c(0, 0, 1))

Coefficients:
         ma1  intercept
      0.1769    13.8655
s.e.  0.1304     0.4505

sigma^2 estimated as 9.126:  log likelihood = -156.53,  aic = 319.07
```

The ar1 and ma1 coefficient estimates are not significant, so it makes sense to model your data as a simple ARIMA(0, 0, 0) (== ARMA(0, 0) == white noise).

Comment: Dear @eillasti thanks for your contribution to this post. I need your help to forecast the next 5 observation for this data. How can I do it?

Comment: The forecast for all observations is just the unconditional mean (`mean(dt)`)

Comment: The point forecast is **13.87097**, while the`mean(dt)=15.238`.

Comment: Ok, what's the next step on forecasting the next values?